# Is this moth orchid irretrievably dying?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, orchids

Leaves have been dying back for some time but the roots always looked fine.  But then the leaves completely dried up and I cut them back to see if there were any viable stem.  When I found these.

[image]

[image]

The other plant is Spanish moss I've got sitting on top so I can spray water on both at the same time.

Comment: looks pretty ded to me, monocots have strange growth habits, I wouldn't toss it until all of the everything looks ded, those roots are still green and storing (maybe even producing) some energy.

Comment: If the stem dies, the whole plant dies as healthy roots can't save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought those black things were scale and this was an impossible to treat scale infection.  But when I put some hydrogen peroxide on the black areas, nothing happened.  I then scraped them and it's just dead stem or buds.  So, I decided harder to try and rescue the plant.  I setup a nursery inside a tall glass vase, and at the bottom I placed some live sphagnum moss.  On top of that I placed the pitiful remains of my moth orchid, and then I put the Spanish moss on top of that to maximise the benefit of the humidor. For extra humidification I placed the vase inside an empty aquarium and put aquarium water into the vase to provide some nutrition.  These are the results a month later.  You can see a new leaf (keiki) appearing at 7 pm on the stem!  The other roots closest to the sphagnum moss have turned dark green.

[image: new leaves forming from the orchid stem]

Even the Spanish moss is enjoying the environment and has started to flower

[image: flowering Spanish moss]

So, with more time I hope to have saved this moth orchid.

Comment: The process I followed is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XgOQQDwJR4